# ejabberd : Cannot view Rooms Tab after login

Tags: xmpp, chat, ejabberd

I am unable to view the "Rooms" tab after user logs in screenshot : http://screencast.com/t/gdJUN21is

Is there a module that needs to be enabled in ejabberd config file. If yes, what is the name of that module...
Any pointers could be great help. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The module that support chat room is `mod_muc` in ejabberd. You should make sure it is enabled in your ejabberd configuration file.

The documentation of that module configuration is in ejabberd Docs site: [Configuring ejabberd MUC module](http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/configuration/#modmuc)

However, please, note that your issue may not be in ejabberd. I am not sure what client you are using and what are the criteria to display the MUC tab. It is possible you need to investigate your XMPP client configuration in more depth.